# How to use PyPI package in a Docker image in GitLab CI pipeline?

Tags: docker, gitlab, cicd, pypi

Currently only one (but in the future more) package is being build and pushed to my GitLab repo's PyPI registry with the following two jobs:

```
build-base-package:
  stage: build
  image: python:slim
  artifacts:
    untracked: true
    paths:
    - base/build
  script:
    - cd base
    - apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade && pip install --upgrade pip && pip install -r requirements.txt
    - pip install wheel build
    - python -m build --wheel
    - ls -R
  tags:
    - myrunner
  interruptible: true 


deploy-base-package-to-registry:
  stage: build
  image: python:slim
  tags:
    - myrunner
  dependencies:
    - build-base-package
  script:
    - apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade && pip install --upgrade pip
    - pip install twine
    - TWINE_PASSWORD=${CI_JOB_TOKEN} TWINE_USERNAME=gitlab-ci-token python -m twine upload --verbose --skip-existing --repository-url ${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/pypi base/dist/*
```

In the same repository I have a `Dockerfile` and some `requirements.txt` that I would like to create my image from. The image has to include `base-package` (the CI jobs above). I do not know however how to even add it to my `requirements.txt` so that it works.

The main (only?) issue I have so far is the requirement to use an access token (PAT or `CI_JOB_TOKEN`) to access the PyPI registry. I don't see how this can work with an image that depends on such a registry for packages.

---

UPDATE: In case someone mentions it, I would prefer not to use the product from the build job (here a `wheel` file), which I can do as long as I am in the same pipeline as far as I know. The knowledge is important since it may be applicable to other use cases such as inter-repo dependencies, where a pipeline from one project uses the package built by a pipeline in another one.

Comment: Installing works just like any other requirement you have -- just add the package name to your `requirements.txt`. When you install, make sure your GitLab package registry is configured as an [additional] index server. Have you tried the examples from [install a PyPI package](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/pypi_repository/#install-a-pypi-package)? What have you tried? Did you have a specific error?

Comment: Yes I have. The problem comes from the access token requirement. It restricts where I can download packages from. If I use `CI_JOB_TOKEN`I am limited to the scope of the CI pipeline in the project. For anything else I have to use  PAT (personal access token), which is something I'd like to avoid using. GAT and PrAT (group and project ATs) are not available on GitLab.com but only on SaaS and self-managed instances. Adding a project to the scope of trusted projects in another project doesn't seem to help one bit in my case.

Comment: Group and project access tokens are available on gitlab.com (SaaS means gitlab.com).

Comment: Ah, thanks. But for me they show as disabled. :D And the option that the documentation states I need to set does not appear in the Web UI. XD

Comment: You do need a Premium or Ultimate subscription to use those features. That may be the case if you don't have that level of subscription entitlement. But you should also be able to use `CI_JOB_TOKEN`. In order for your job token to access other projects -- you must [change the settings](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/ci_job_token.html#add-a-project-to-the-job-token-allowlist) of the project with the package registry to allow access to the other project's job tokens or [allow any project](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/ci_job_token.html#allow-any-project-to-access-your-project) to access